# How to build a PHP middle server between another server & clients?

Tags: php, http, caching, browser-cache

I'm trying to build a PHP server(i'll call it here server1) , that works as a middle server between another web server (server2) and clients.

The reason I'm doing that, I want to hide the API Key I'm using to access the server2 from server1. Also, I want to decrease number of calls to server2.

My question is, How can I do something that caches the calls from server1 to server2? Is there a module or something to use in PHP? I don't want each call from the clients to produce a call to server2.

another requirement is to cache the feeds from server2 for 5 minutes only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is simpler:
http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/php-caching.php

Answer (score 1):

Could Varnish be an alternative?
https://www.varnish-cache.org/

Comment: Using a proper caching proxy is definitely preferable if possible.  However, OP mentions `I want to hide the API Key I'm using to access the server2 from server1` which may complicate things a little.  Depending on how the API call is constructed, it may nor may not be trivial to inject the API key in varnish.

Answer (score 0):

What you want it a PHP proxy, such as:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-proxy/